# How can I change the src path from img that doesn't have id identifier using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change first path of my img tag, but this code doesn't work to me.
My HTML code

```
<div class="home">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
</div>
```

My JQuery code

```
$("img[src$='a.jpg']")[0].attr('src','change.jpg');
```

I want my HTML being like this

```
<div class="home">
    <img src="change.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
</div>
```

Can anybody help me to figure out this case please? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `..")[0].` will give you the DOM node which doesn't have a jquery `attr` method - remove the `[0]` and replace with `.eq(0)`

```
$("img[src$='a.jpg']").eq(0).attr('src','change.jpg');
```

```js
$("img[src$='https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg']").eq(0).attr('src','https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ4V5.jpg');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
    <img width=100 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg">
    <img width=100 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg">
    <img width=100 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Let assume that you have more img tags in your page and the filename is unknown you can achieve it like

```
<div class="home">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
    <img src="a.jpg">
</div>
$('.home img:first-child').attr('src','change.jpg');
```